# Minimum cart amount for subcategories of a specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to only allow orders up to $32 for a specific category (it has some subcategories), or within the combination of 4 subcategories (coffee1, popular-blends, subscriptions, chaiandchocolate).

Based on [Minimum cart amount for specific product categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156813/minimum-cart-amount-for-specific-product-categories-in-woocommerce/62161964#62161964) answer code, here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_cart_coffee_items' );
function check_cart_coffee_items() {
    $categories = array('coffee'); // Defined targeted product categories
    $threshold  = 32; // Defined threshold amount

    $cart       = WC()->cart;
    $cart_items = $cart->get_cart();
    $subtotal   = $cart->subtotal;
    $subtotal  -= $cart->get_cart_discount_total() + $cart->get_cart_discount_tax_total();
    $found      = false;

    foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Check for specific product categories
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; // A category is found
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }

    if ( $found && $subtotal < $threshold ) {
        // Display an error notice (and avoid checkout)
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( "You must order at least %s of coffee" ), wc_price($threshold) ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

But I cannot get it working for either the overall coffee category or for any individual subcategories. Some help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead, that will check for items from all subcategories of "Coffee" main category (and from non discounted subtotal including taxes from that subcategories):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'minimum_order_amount_for_subcategories' );
function minimum_order_amount_for_subcategories() {
    $term_slug   = 'coffee'; // <==  Define the targeted main product category slug
    $threshold   = 32; // <==  Define the minimum amount threshold

    $taxonomy    = 'product_cat'; // WooCommerce product category taxonomy
    $subtotal    = 0; // Itintializing
    $found       = false; // Itintializing
    
    // Get the children terms Ids from the main product category term slug
    $main_term   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
    $childen_ids = get_term_children( $main_term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $terms_ids   = array_merge( array($main_term->term_id), $childen_ids);
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for specific product category children term ids
        if ( has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; // At least subcategory is found
            
            // Get non discounted subtotal including taxes from subcategories
            $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax']; 
        }
    }

    if ( $found && $subtotal < $threshold ) {
        // Display an error notice (and avoid checkout)
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __( "You must order at least %s of %s", "woocommerce" ),
            wc_price($threshold),
            '"<strong>' . ucfirst($term_slug) . '</strong>"' 
        ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). it should works.

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something wrong.  I inerted the code in my child theme functions.php, but it's not throwing the message when it should.  I wonder if I do not have my product categories set up correctly?  This is how they are set up: https://snipboard.io/ChXa3B.jpg.  Maybe better if I just do a main category instead of a parent category?